# Powershell script not running from php

Tags: php, powershell

I am running one PowerShell script from PHP like the below example

```
$ff = shell_exec(env("POWERSHELL_PATH") . ' '.Storage::path('public\ps\test.ps1').' 2>&1');
Storage::disk('public')->put('log.txt', $ff);
```

above code runs PowerShell script and stores result in log.txt file.
It's running fine when test.ps1 has the below content

```
$version = $PSversionTable
$version.PSVersion.Major
```

but when test.ps1 has the below content

```
connect-exchangeonline
Get-MalwareFilterPolicy -Identity Default | Select-Object EnableFileFilter
```

it gives me the below error.

```
Error Acquiring Token:
System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Features.WinFormsLegacyWebUi.WebUI.<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.<FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.<FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<GetTokenResponseAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.AdminApiProvider.Authentication.MSALTokenProvider.<GetAccessTokenAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
New-ExoPSSession : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\Program\Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\2.0.5\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:475 char:30
+ ... PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ExoPSSession], AggregateException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewExoPSSess 
ion
```

I think it is related pop-up window for authorization but don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Connect-ExchangeOnline is defaulting to an interactive login as you suspect. You need to look at the documentation for how to connect using either a credential object which you can store encrypted on disk, or a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have done it following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#example-4

where I have created one app in tenant and given it proper permissions, then I create one self-signed certificate and assign that certificate to that app. now I can easily connect to the exchange using below command.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "FFF39295FB842B345FV3012B27272C693C5BB725" -AppID "875d7314-3247-4d3d-b419-0c9060334a5f" -Organization "tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is related pop-up window for authorization...

You are right! That's exactly what the error message is telling you:

```
Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in 
UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation.
```

As Robin already stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191701/powershell-script-not-running-from-php#comment129265547_73191701), you have to provide authentication parameters to [`Connect-ExchangeOnline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline), so that it does not have to prompt you for them interactively.

It supports multiple different authentication methods. Depending on how you want to authenticate, have a look at:

- `-UserPrincipalName` for modern authentication
- `-UserPrincipalName -UseRPSSession` for modern authentication with Basic Authentication
- `-CertificateFilePath`/`-CertificateThumbprint`/`-Certificate` for public key authentication
- `-Credential`

Comment: -UserPrincipalName also only works with pop-up window. could you give me any example with -Certificate or -Credential?

Comment: Here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#example-3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Get-Credential for possible alternatives.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.2

```
$User = "Domain01\User01"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@sSwOrd" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

connect-exchangeonline -Credential $Credential
Get-MalwareFilterPolicy -Identity Default | Select-Object EnableFileFilter
```

Comment: Get-Credential also opens with pop-up window that stores credentials for powershell